# Why DateOfBirth saving in AddressBook one day before?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, datepicker, abaddressbook

I'm using datePicker to save the dateOfBirth in my app and I'm saving it in addressBook, but it always saves a day before dateOfBirth (but in calendar event saved same date). It's strange because I'm setting:

```
self.datePicker.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
self.datePicker.calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
```

Why is it like this?